# Using Pipe in a component in Ionic 3 does not work

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3, pipe, components

I created some reusable components that I can use in other pages that needs to use **pipes**. However when I try to import the Pipe the html does not know. It returns me an error below.

> Error: Template parse errors: The pipe 'image' could not be found

I know using pipes in a **Pages** works but how can I work with components using pipes?

To explain this further more. I have a page called **accounts.ts** and that page use the `<orders>` **component** which I render it like this.

```
 <orders (viewOrder)="viewAccount($event)" [orders]="orderCancelled" *ngIf="accountsHasLoaded"></orders>
```

And in the `ngModule` of that page I declared this.

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AccountPage,
  ],
  imports: [
    PipesModule,
    NgCalendarModule,
    ComponentsModule,
    IonicPageModule.forChild(AccountPage),
  ],
})
```

This is the ngModule of thee **accounts** page that will use the **orders component**.

Here is my code below in my **component.ts**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'orders',
  templateUrl: 'orders.html',
  providers: [
    ImagePipe
  ]
})
```

It still does not work when I replace the **ImagePipe** in the provider with **PipesModule**.

and in my **html**

```
  <img [src]="order?.client?.image?.url | image: 'original'" onError="this.src='assets/imgs/No_Image_Available.jpg';">
```

The pipes image works well with **pages** but when I try to use it in a component it does not work.

This is my **pipes module** below

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { ChatDatePipe } from './chat-date/chat-date';
import { MomentPipe } from './moment/moment';
import { DatepickerFormatPipe } from './datepicker-format/datepicker-format';
import { ImagePipe } from './image/image';
@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        ChatDatePipe,
        MomentPipe,
        DatepickerFormatPipe,
        ImagePipe
    ],
    imports: [],
    exports: [
        ChatDatePipe,
        MomentPipe,
        DatepickerFormatPipe,
        ImagePipe
    ],
    providers: [
        ImagePipe
    ]
})
export class PipesModule { }
```

Appreciate if someone could help.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: post your code for image pipe

Comment: Did you try to use “ionic generate pipe” command and see how default implementation is working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to declare the pipe  in module declaration:

```
declarations: [ ImagePipe ],
providers: [ImagePipe ]
```

Comment: it returns me this error when declaring it in the component. `Argument of type '{ selector: string; templateUrl: string; declarations: undefined[]; providers: (typeof ImagePipe)[]; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Component'.
  Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'declarations' does not exist in type 'Component'.`

Comment: Sorry I edited the question declare it as an provider but still does not work.

Comment: It turns out I am not using lazy loading in the components due to the generated of ionic command using `ionic g component namehere`. It has one **component.module** for all of them. When I import it it now works on every component. But I think this is a bad practice? Should I lazy load my components?

Answer (score 1):

Just perform following checks

1.Check if you have given desired pipe name.

```
@Pipe({ name: 'image' })
export class ImagePipe {

}
```

2.You have declared the pipe into the module

```
   @NgModule({
      declarations: [
        ImagePipe,
      ],
    })
```

Comment: Make sure you are declaring the Pipe in right 'Module'

Comment: The generated component of orders does not have module. I declare it it in the PipesModule like this. `@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        ChatDatePipe,
        MomentPipe,
        DatepickerFormatPipe,
        ImagePipe
    ],
    imports: [],
    exports: [
        ChatDatePipe,
        MomentPipe,
        DatepickerFormatPipe,
        ImagePipe
    ],
    providers: [
        ImagePipe
    ]
})
export class PipesModule { }`

Answer (score 0):

For what I can see you can try this
Try this:

```
<img [src]="order?.client?.image?.url | ImagePipe: 'original'" onError="this.src='assets/imgs/No_Image_Available.jpg';">
```

Your pipe is called ImagePipe, not image.

if this doesn't work, post your ImagePipe code

Answer (score 0):

This is how you use a Pipe in a component in Ionic Framework:

Code is for mycomponent.ts file:

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';

import { MyPipe } from '../../pipes/mypipe/mypipe';

@Component({
  selector: 'mycomponent',
  templateUrl: 'mycomponent.component.html',
  providers: [ MyPipe ]
})
export class MyComponent {

@Input() param: string;  

  constructor( private myPipe: MyPipe) {

  }

  getFilename( value: string ) {
    return this.myPipe.transform(value);
  } 

}
```

And in your mycomponent.html file:

```
<div>
    <img src="assets/imgs/svg/{{ getFilename(param) }}.svg">
</div>
```

The method you call is in curly braces